# how to use external code python in python files

Tags: python, request, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, subprocess

my script gets the title tag and modify this and généraite a variable
and i would like to use the script separately on the principal python script
on the secondary script the généraited variable is

```
print (oname_cleanedup)
```

i want to use this variable on my script

code of my secondary script

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import subprocess
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import  requests
import  re
import sys

olinks = sys.argv[1]

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537)'}
session = requests.Session()
response = session.get(olinks, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
oname = soup.find("title")
if oname.text.find('Saison') >= 0:
    regexp = r'(.*?\s+-\s+S)aison\s+(\d+)\s+\xc9.*?(\d+)(.*)'
    subst = "{title} {season:02d} Ep {episode}"
else:
    regexp = r'(.*?\s+-)(\s+)\xc9.*?(\d+)(.*)'
    subst = "{title} Ep {episode}"
oname_cleanedup = re.sub(regexp,
                         lambda m: subst.format(title=m.group(1), season=int(m.group(2)) if m.group(2).find(" ")==-1 else "", episode=m.group(3)),
                         oname.text)

print(oname_cleanedup)
```

sorry i forget information

I wants to import my script

```
  import sys
    sys.path.append('files/')
    from my script.py import my fonction
```

juste  How to define my function on the secondary script

Comment: Have you tried importing it?

Comment: i forget information i have edited the topic ty

Comment: my secondary script is the desired functions juste how to import this big script and get the variable sorry im a debutent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass args to the script you can use subprocess:

```
from subprocess import check_output

c = check_output(["python","my_script.py","http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032363/how-to-use-external-code-python-in-python-files#28032363"])
print(c)
request - how to use external code python in python files - Stack Overflow
```

If you try `from my_script import oname_cleanedup` you will get an error as you have supplied no args. You should maybe put it all in a function and pass the url to that function so you can import it.

```
def function(olinks):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537)'}
    session = requests.Session()
    response = session.get(olinks, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
    oname = soup.find("title")
    if oname.text.find('Saison') >= 0:
        regexp = r'(.*?\s+-\s+S)aison\s+(\d+)\s+\xc9.*?(\d+)(.*)'
        subst = "{title} {season:02d} Ep {episode}"
    else:
        regexp = r'(.*?\s+-)(\s+)\xc9.*?(\d+)(.*)'
        subst = "{title} Ep {episode}"
    return re.sub(regexp,lambda m: subst.format(title=m.group(1), season=int(m.group(2)) if m.group(2).find(" ")==-1 else "", episode=m.group(3)),oname.text)
```

Then:

```
 from myscript import function
 oname_cleanedup = function(url)
```

I have a suspicion that beautifulsoup can do a lot of what you are doing with your regex.

Comment: it works :) ty   `I have a suspicion that beautifulsoup can do a lot of what you are doing with your regex.`  What do you mean?

Comment: i would need to see an example url but among other things you can use re.compile with find and findall etc.. Also you don't need a Session you can just use requests.get.

Comment: a url http://animedigitalnetwork.fr/video/assassination-classroom/5886-episode-2-lecon-de-base-ball  I want to get back the title and to modify it then to use him(it)

Comment: @hideyoshi, off for a coffee. i will update the answer with a few pointers in a bit

Comment: i don no have a news ?

Comment: I will let you know when i edit. I am away from my laptop for a while!